# Changing a shared variable with .value() for multiprocessing and cv2

Tags: python, windows, opencv, multiprocessing

I have written a Python script for a project in which I record the behavior of a subject while doing a task. For this purpose I am using the `openCV`  module on a Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7. Because I want to be able to later align the video, with the time stamps I collect during the task, both operations need to run in parallel. Therefore I have been trying to work with the `multiprocessing` module. This works so far that both processes run in parallel. The issue is the stopping part. I create a simple boolean variable that, if the actual code is finished, changes to 0 (False). I want to pass this variable to the process to exit the code run in the process. However, this does not seem to work. Could anyone advise me how to fix this issue ?

This is the code that should run in the process

```
def camera(running):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    valueTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
    filename = valueTime.strftime('_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.avi')
    path = 'C:/Users/csc/Desktop/Videos'
    pathname = os.path.join(path,filename)
    print "Create video file "+pathname
    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathname,fourcc, 28.0, (640,480))
    #out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',-1, 30.0, (640,480))

    while running.value==1:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        out.write(grayImage)

        cv2.imshow('frame',grayImage)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        if running.value==0:
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The main code (generalized example):

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Value

running = Value('i', 1)

while timer_for_approx_20_min:
    vidrecord = Process(target=camera(running, ), args=(running,))
    vidrecord.start()

    # Code for the task 

    running.value = 0
```

Comment: It should be `target=camera`, not `target=camera(running,)`.

Comment: If i run it that way, the camera wont start at all

Comment: `target=camera(running,)` is just calling the function in the current process and setting the target to the return value, which is `None`. That's unquestionably wrong. It needs to be `Process(target=camera, args=(running,))`. If it's not working, add some debug print statements to inspect `cap` and `cap.isOpened()`.